# How to bind a primitive type list to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need a DataGrid with just a single column of double type to be able to add, edit and delete entries from a local list variable.

My list is defined as an observable collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<double> Values = 
    new ObservableCollection<double>() { 1.0, 20 };
```

How to I bind the list to a DataGrid without wrapping it by a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a data model with named properties (to use column auto generation) you will need to explicitly define the column layout by setting the `DataGrid.DataGridTextColumn`:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" IsReadOnly="True" >  
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value"
                          Binding="{Binding}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private ObservableCollection<double> values;
  public ObservableCollection<double> Values
  {
    get => this.values;
    set
    {
      this.values = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // Constructor
  public void ViewModel()
  {
    // Initialize the data binding source of the DataGrid
    this.Values = new ObservableCollection<double>() { 1.0, 20 };
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**Remarks**
When binding the cell to the `double` values directly (or when using empty binding syntax in general e.g. `{Binding}` or `{Binding Path=.}`) `BindingMode.TwoWay` and therefore cell editing is not possible. This means `BindingMode.TwoWay` requires a property. Therefore to make cells editable the cell's binding source must expose the value via a property that is exposed by a wrapping type (data model or POCO).

Comment: Thanks. The solution works in general but there was "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath." error when editing a cell. Got that fixed by explicitely defining "Path=." in the column binding.

Comment: Yes, because of the edit functionality that the `DataGrid` offers, the `Binding.Mode` is `TwoWay` by default (to update the `Binding.Source` on edit completed.

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick to claim the fix. With the dot specified the error is no longer shown when starting cell edit, but still occurs when the change is commited. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: The point  is that an empty binding (`{Binding}` or `{Binding Path=.}`) would set the source value itself as the binding source. E.g. when editing the value to change from '12' to '10' the binding can't directly update the value '12'  since it is not a reference (or pointer). The binding would assign a new value instance to a property that references the values. That's why Two-Way bindings require a property (or indexer) to as binding source - a path.

Comment: For instance when having a property named `Value` that references a value type of type `double` and making the binding modify it (like in a Two-Way binding), a new value will be assigned to the `Value` property instead of modifying the value directly. So the solution to your problem is either to make the `DataGrid` read-only  to disable editing (so that you can set the binding to `OneWay`) or to wrap the values into a type that exposes the value via a property.

Comment: I added this info as remarks to the answer to make this clear.